# Could anyone help me with this Solidity Fibonacci challenge please?

Tags: solidity, bytecode

What is the shortest runtime bytecode you can write for a contract that satisfies both the following:

- Accepts calldata of length 32 bytes representing one uint256 (no function selector)
- Returns, as one uint256, the Fibonacci number at the index of the input (the sequence can start at
  either 0 or 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a challenge, you should try to tackle it yourself. I understand that maybe you don't understand the problem well, and I will clarify it to you, then I will spell out the logic and then I'll show you a solution.

But when I clarify what you need to do, try to solve it yourself. If you can't, then check the logic I will show you. If you still can't figure it out, then check my solution:

**Clarification**

They want you to create a contract that has a function "with no function selector" (meaning, it's the `fallback` function). That function should receive `calldata` parameter of length 32 bytes`that will contain data that you need to treat as a`uint256`number (by decoding it). Let's call this number`n`.

Then, you need to calculate the Fibonacci sequence up to that `n` number and return it.

As we know, the Fibonacci sequence is as follows:

`0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, ...`
The first is `0`, the second is `1`, the third is `1`, and the fourth is `2`. Basically, the Fibonacci sequence is a sequence of numbers where each number is composed of the sum of the previous 2 numbers, starting with `0, 1`.

Compile it (maybe with Remix), take the runtime bytecode, and submit it.

Check the `fallback` function docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/contracts.html?highlight=fallback#fallback-function

Check the `abi.encode`, `abi.encodePacked` and `abi.decode` functions docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=abi.decode#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions

Think about it and try to solve it yourself now.

**Logic**

Implement the following `fallback` function:

`js fallback(bytes calldata _input) external returns(bytes memory output)`

Inside it, decode the `_input` as a `uint256` type (the `uint256` type has 32 bytes), in a variable called `n`.

Calculate the Fibonacci sequence up to `n`.

Return the result encoding it as bytes (with `abi.encode` or `abi.encodePacked`).

Compile it (maybe with Remix), take the runtime bytecode, and submit it.

That's it!

Try to solve it yourself.

If you can't, then take a look at my solution below.

**Solution**

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

contract Fibonacci {

    uint256 public input;
    uint256 public result;

    fallback(bytes calldata _input) external returns(bytes memory output) {

        (uint256 n) = abi.decode(_input, (uint256));

        uint256 v1 = 0;
        uint256 v2 = 1;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            v2 = v1 + v2;
            v1 = v2 - v1;
        }

        input = n; // No need to do this, just for debugging.
        result = v2; // No need to do this, just for debugging.

        // If called from another contract, the contract will receive this as the bytes response
        return abi.encode(v2);

    }

}
```

Compile it (maybe with Remix), take the runtime bytecode, and submit it. In my case, it's:

`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`
In Remix, click on Compilation Details and click on Runtime Bytecode:

[image]

And get it:

[image]

There are many ways to solve the Fibonacci sequence. The solution that I used is very efficient in terms of time and space complexity. This solution uses little gas. Solving it with recursion in Solidity would be really gas expensive. You can try other solutions if you want.

Comment: What about if I want to find the shortest runtime bytecode?

Comment: Try removing the state variables `input` and `result`.

Comment: Okay, yes it helps. What about if I want to solve it with another method i.e., using the formula Fn = {[(√5 + 1) / 2] ^n} / √5 ? Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Solidity does not support the square root math function natively yet. Implementing it would still use a loop too and that could be expensive anyways. But you could try it. Check this answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2910/can-i-square-root-in-solidity

Comment: This answer gives a runtime bytecode of 590 bytes. The question asks me for a runtime bytecode shorter than 50 bytes.

Comment: What is the shortest runtime bytecode you can write for a contract that satisfies both the following:
* Accepts calldata of length 32 bytes representing one uint256 (no function selector)
* Returns, as one uint256, the Fibonacci number at the index of the input (the sequence can start at either 0 or 1)
Provide all working solutions as you optimize, along with:
* opcodes as mnemonics
* comments showing the contents of stack and memory as appropriate
There are valid solutions shorter than 50 bytes.
Example, the shortest runtime bytecode for returning the chainId is:
0x463d52593df3.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I wrote a Medium article on this - containing the same (and more) information as my answer on your post, see https://medium.com/@annelohmeijer/develop-evm-assembly-opcode-logic-for-fibonacci-107f92dbc9d1

#### Approach

The approach here is to solve the problem by constructing the runtime bytecode yourself using opcodes (low-level language of a stack machine like the EVM). Writing an algorithm in Solidity or Yul and compile that is not going to give you a solution shorter than 50 bytes in length; an empty contract already compiles to a few hundred bytes. Writing an algorithm in pseudocode does help you though in order to identify what your opcode blocks should do.

[This medium article](https://medium.com/@kalexotsu/writing-evm-logic-in-opcodes-deploying-opcode-logic-on-chain-205618fee38d) is a great read on how to write opcodes from scratch and test and deploy them. The [EVM playground](https://www.evm.codes/?fork=merge) is the best place to play around and to get familiar with opcodes, stack, memory, the EVM, etc.

#### Algorithm

[Jeremy's answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/135369/112210) already provide a great start: using the fallback function (since no function selector), and an algorithm to solve the problem. In similar pseudocode:

```
contract Fibonacci {
    fallback() payable external returns (bytes memory k) {
        initialize j = 0
        initialize k = 1
        for {i = 2, i <= n, i++}:
            m = k + j
            j = k
            k = m
       return k
    }
```

Now the challenge is: how do you translate this to opcodes?

#### Separate blocks

First split the function into manageable pieces that do a particular task:

1. Load calldata n to the stack
2. Initialize variables.
3. Loop condition: determine if we need to execute the loop body. If n is 0 or 1, jump to return anchor. This is handled by instantiating i = 2.
4. Loop body

   1. Increment counter i
   2. Execute body: Fibonacci logic
5. Jump back to loop condition
6. Return block

Then, piece by piece, develop the opcode logic that performs the task at hand. Just like Jeremy I recommend to try yourself. Start small: how do I pass calldata to the stack. How do I return data from the stack to the caller. Next: how do I create for-loop in opcodes that does nothing in the body. You get the drill. Using Excel to keep track of your work and adding an additional column with the content of the stack after each operation really helps (see below table).

## Solution

When you have figured out how to construct the above opcode blocks separately, you can combine them and iterate to make sure that together the logic still checks out. In overview:

| **Opcode block** | **Name** | **Value** | **Function** | **Stack after operation** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Load calldata** | PUSH1 | 0x00 | Offset to load calldata | [0] |
|  | CALLDATALOAD |  |  | [n] |
| **Prepare / initalize for loop** | PUSH1 | 0x01 | Instantiate k = 1 | [k][n] |
|  | PUSH1 | 0x00 | Instantiate j = 0 | [j][k][n] |
|  | SWAP2 |  |  | [n][k][j] |
|  | PUSH1 | 0x02 | Instantiate i = 2 | [i][n][k][j] |
| **Loop condition [loopcondition]** | JUMPDEST |  | Check if we need to run the loop body |  |
|  | DUP2 |  | Duplicate n | [n][i][n][k][j] |
|  | DUP2 |  | Duplicate i | [i][n][i][n][k][j] |
|  | GT |  | Check if i > n, if true jump to return block | [0/1][i][n][k][j] |
|  | PUSH1 | 0x1c | Add jump destination of return block | [returnblock][0/1][i][n][k][j] |
|  | JUMPI |  |  |  |
| **Loop body: increment counter** | PUSH1 | 0x01 | Add increment for i | [1][i][n][k][j] |
|  | ADD |  | Increment i | [i+1][n][k][j] |
| **Loop body: Fibonacci** | SWAP2 |  | Swap k with i | [k][n][i+1][j] |
|  | DUP1 |  | Duplicate k | [k][k][n][i+1][j] |
|  | SWAP4 |  | Swap k with j | [j][k][n][i+1][k] |
|  | ADD |  | Add k + j = k* | [k*][n][i+1][k] |
|  | SWAP2 |  | Swap k* with i | [i+1][n][k*][k] |
| **Jump back to loop condition** | PUSH1 | 0x0a | Add jump destination of loop condition | [loopcondition][i+1][n][k*][k] |
|  | JUMP |  |  |  |
| **Return block [returnblock]** | JUMPDEST |  | Jump destination for return block |  |
|  | POP |  | Pop i off the stack | [n][k*][k] |
|  | POP |  | Pop n off the stack | [k*][k] |
|  | PUSH1 | 0x00 | MSTORE offset | [0][k*][k] |
|  | MSTORE |  | Store to be returned value in memory |  |
|  | PUSH1 | 0x20 | Return size 32 bytes | [20] |
|  | PUSH1 | 0x00 | Return offset | [0][20] |
|  | RETURN |  | Return k* to caller |  |

The bytecode representation of this solution is

```
600035600160009160025b818111601c576001019180930191600a565b505060005260206000f3
```

which is **39 bytes** in length, satisfying your requirements. It's a valid solution for returning the Fibonacci number at index n, starting at index 1 (if you pass 0 as calldata - in hex padded to 32 bytes of course - then it returns 1, which is not correct). Paste it in the EVM playground and see for yourself.

#### Optimize

This is not the shortest possible runtime bytecode - for example one can easily get rid of the `SWAP2` in the fifth instruction by changing the order of initializing the for-loop variables and loading call data - but I think it demonstrates how to get to a solution yourself. Hope this helps.